# @media queries not working on my iPad

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have the following media query setup:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 959px)`

and it works when I size down my browser, but it doesn’t work when my iPad is in portrait. If I add `and (max-device-width: 959px)` it works on my iPad, but not in my browser. And I need it to work in both.

What’s going wrong on my [web](http://www.yn47.com/m/5/pans-labyrinth-avi.html) ? Thanks

Comment: Add additional media queries. One size literally does not fit all. Also, consider making your queries more explicit `@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }`  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Try `@media all ...` instead of `screen`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely the virtual viewport that some devices provide.  The viewport is larger than the physical screen and content is scaled down by the browser.  If you want to work in device pixels you need to add a meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This tells the browser to set the viewport to the same size as the device with no pixel scaling.